# Contacts CursorLoader return empty result

Tags: android, settings, contacts, android-permissions, android-cursorloader

I have application with manifest permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

My activity try to load contacts:

```
    eDeviceRecordsLoader contactsLoader = new eDeviceRecordsLoader(this);
    loaderActivity.getLoaderManager().initLoader(R.id.ab_control_device_records_loader, null, contactsLoader);
```

eDeviceRecordsLoader:

```
    public class eDeviceRecordsLoader implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
    {
            public eDeviceRecordsLoader(Context _context)
            {
                    context = _context;
            }
            @Override
            public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int _id, Bundle _args)
            {
                    loaderId = _id;
                    return new CursorLoader(context,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                            PROJECTION,
                            SELECTION,
                            null,
                            null);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> _loader, Cursor _data)
            {
                    if(_loader.getId() != loaderId) { return; }
                    if(_data.moveToFirst())
                    {
                            eDeviceRecords records  = new eDeviceRecords();
                            do
                            {
                                    String  currentContactLookupKey = _data.getString(_data.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                                    long    currentContactId        = _data.getLong(_data.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                                    records.put(currentContactId, new eDeviceRecord(currentContactId, currentContactLookupKey));
                            }
                            while(_data.moveToNext());
                            //another work
                    }
            }
    protected static final String   SELECTION   = "(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1" + ")"; 
    protected static final String[] PROJECTION  = 
    {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED,
    };
    }
```

80% of phones work correctly and load contacts. But some phones has additional app security settings for permissions(Version API < 23) and can lock app access(constantly or by pin/password or need approve from user) for contacts and other permissions. Permission granted in manifest but app has no access and cursor always is empty.

Question: How can I check this additional permission and alert user to grant them?

Comment: off topic: why do you iterate over the `Cursor`? why dont you use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` ?

Comment: I'm send all contact to additional processing - check add/delete contacts - and then show

Comment: are you sure the `Cursor` is empty? tried `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor()` ?

Comment: if there was not an empty I have not posted here

Comment: Are you asking how to prompt the user for the permission at runtime for api 23?

Comment: No. In my case api  <23 version. Phone Xiami Mi3 - 4.1.1 and Meizu MX5 - 5.0.1. But this phones have additional security settings for permissions. I want to disable this settings or promt user to disable.

Comment: how do you know it has something to do with additional security settings? did you try null `SELECTION`? maybe it is related to `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` which could be not working on those devices (in which case you should use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone`)?

Comment: I'm try use NULL for SELECTION & PROJECTION. Result also is empty. If I disable additional permissions code is work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what is occurring with the device at this time, I would recommend taking the advice of the comments and ensuring that there is no flaw in the code, after this; you could put in some sort of lock screen listener and handle you app like this, so a message is displayed, if you are unable to send a toast when the screen is locked, then log when it is locked and display a warning before this, or you could put in a warning at the first use of the app or every time the app starts (annoying for the user).

When deciding how to alert the user, it would then depend upon how aggressively you would like to do this.

You could:

1. Put is a splash screen upon first start up of the app informing the user of the pin restrictions that may occur.
2. Create a toast with a warning that a pin may be required.
3. Create a dialog that the user must close to ensure user interaction, hence acknowledgment.

Not the ideal solution you are looking for I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my case contacts are loaded at first start of application(no lock screen or something else). Only one permission(CONTACTS) is denied. I can't solve programmatically is phone book empty or I have no permissions and should show alert for user.